# ConnectableObservable. Replay with different values?

Tags: java, rx-java

How can I replay using a connected observable?  It always calls the onComplete.  I want to be able to fire multiple events with different values

Ex:

```
    Observable<String> interval = Observable.just("A", "B");
    ConnectableObservable<String> published = interval.publish();
    CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    mCompositeSubscription.add(published.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            out.println("adsf");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            out.println(s);

        }
    }));

    published.connect();

    //  Now I want it to reuse the Observer or Subscriber to get the new events
    interval = Observable.just("C", "D");
    published = interval.replay();
```

I don't want to continually new up Subscribers to do this. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html). Use one of them (depending on your needs) instead of `Observable.just`, `publish` and `connect`.

```
Subject<String,String> interval = ReplaySubject.create();
interval.onNext("A");
interval.onNext("B");
//use asObservable before exposing your subject
Observable<String> published = interval.asObserbale;
CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
mCompositeSubscription.add(published.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        out.println("adsf");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        out.println(s);

    }
}));

//send new values to Subcribers
interval.onNext("C");
interval.onNext("D");
```